# Why dont I get any terminal output after hot code loading in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

While trying to understand how to work with servers and hot code loading I stumbled over a problem which I have stripped down to the following code:

**server.erl**

```
-module(server).
-export([start/0, connect/1]).

start() ->
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(8080, [binary, {packet, raw}, {active, true}]),
    spawn(?MODULE, connect, [Listen]).

connect(Listen) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    spawn(?MODULE, connect, [Listen]),
    loop(Socket).

loop(Socket) ->
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Data} ->
            io:format("1st version received ~p~n", [Data]),
            loop(Socket);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            io:format("socket closed~n")
    end.
```

**client.erl**

```
-module(client).
-export([request/0]).

request() ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect("localhost", 8080, [{packet, raw}, binary]),
    gen_tcp:send(Socket, <<"Hello">>).
```

Starting the server and sending a request creates the expected output.

```
1> server:start().
<0.62.0>
2> client:request().
ok
1st version received <<"Hello">>
```

After changing the format statement to "2nd version", compiling and loading the code and executing two requests (because the connect/1 process currently waiting for connections was spawned before the change) the result is still as expected.

```
3> c(server).       
{ok,server}
4> client:request().
ok
1st version received <<"Hello">>
5> client:request().
ok
2nd version received <<"Hello">>
```

However, after compiling and loading the code twice in a row, there is no output printed in the terminal any more, although the server is obviously still running, since gen_tcp:connect returns a socket.

```
6> c(server).
{ok,server}
7> c(server).
{ok,server}
8> client:request().
ok
```

I suspect that this behaviour has something to do with erlang killing all processes with code older than two versions but I fail to really understand what is happening here.
Since this is educational I am more interested in knowing why this exact code doesn't work rather than an actual solution to the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty certain this is the two-versions limit.

If you want to confirm that, replace the calls from `spawn(...)` to `spawn_link(...)` -- if the processes die, your shell will crash as well and you'll know they have been killed.

Another way to test it is whether you can replace the following:

```
6> c(server).
{ok,server}
7> c(server).
{ok,server}
8> client:request().
ok
```

By:

```
6> c(server).
{ok,server}
7> client:request().
ok
8> c(server).
{ok,server}
9> client:request().
ok
```

If this works fine, the difference is the message in the middle that allows the code to update to a newer code version of the fully-qualified function call (`Module:Fun(Args)`), preventing the crash.

Comment: Using spawn_link shows the processes getting killed after two updates and it still works, when a message is sent in between. I got confused about which processes are connected, but it is starting to make sense now.